# Can lodash debounce be used in a state-less React component without using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I would like to use lodash `debounce` to prevent a button onClick from being run more than once in the event of multiple, rapid clicks. The button is in stateless functional component and from what I've read ([in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616536/lodash-debounce-in-react-functional-component-not-working)), `debounce` will not work in functional components due the debounced function being new each render.

One way to solve this seems to be to use the `useCallback` react hook but, unfortunately, the project is currently at react version 15.6.1 and it is not feasible to upgrade at this time. I can also  get `debounce` to work if I convert the component to a stateful component or if I pass in an already debounced submit function, but I think the best case outcome would be maintaining the functional component while still having it be able to protect against multiple submissions for any submit function.

Is it possible to get debounce to work inside a functional component **without** using hooks?

Here is my functional component for which debounce isn't working:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Lodash from 'lodash';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

export const ConfirmSubmitModal = props => {
    const { submit } = props;

    const debouncedSubmit = Lodash.debounce(() => {
        submit();
    }, 3000, { "leading": true, "trailing": false });

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal>
                  <Button onClick={debouncedSubmit}>Submit</Button>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: `submit` is being passed through props, would it be feasible to debounce it before passing it down to `ConfirmSubmitModal`?

Comment: @schu34 it is feasible and that does work. In some cases though, I think it could be better to have the debouncing done inside the submit component so that the user of the component doesn't have to replicate the debouncing code or remember to debounce the submit function. Though maybe that is the best way to do it and the potential code duplication can be handled in another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create something similar to `useCallback` hook using `_.memoize()`. As long as the `submit` function passed via the props won't change, `getDebouncedSubmit` will return the same debounced function.

```js
_.memoize.Cache = WeakMap; // use a weak map as _.memoize cache to prevent memory leaks

const getDebouncedSubmit = _.memoize(submit => 
  _.debounce(() => {
    submit();
  }, 3000, { "leading": true, "trailing": false })
);

const ConfirmSubmitModal = ({ submit }) => {
  const debouncedSubmit = getDebouncedSubmit(submit);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={debouncedSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const submit = () => console.log('clicked');

ReactDOM.render(
  <ConfirmSubmitModal submit={submit} />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: I ended up just using a stateful class, as I had difficulties with getting the modal to close with this approach (perhaps due to something else in my app). That said, this seems like a good solution in general, thank you!

Comment: I've updated the solution with a WeakMap as the memoize cache.